# Magento2 Overide \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery

Tags: magento2, blocks, overrides

I try to override the `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery` in my module.

I added the below line to my di.xml file for override above block

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View\GalleryXY" />
```

and I create the **GalleryXY.php** file and override methods but it does not work.

```
<?php 
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View;


class GalleryXY extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery{

public function doDebugg() {

    return 'blub';
    }
  }
?>
```

can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<?php 
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View;

class GalleryXY extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery{
    public function getGalleryImages() {
        die(__METHOD__);
    }
}
```

Comment: in gallery.phtml file the declation of $block i have to change or?
to 
/app/design/frontend/Wallstyle/wsdefault/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml

/**
 * Product media data template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery
 */

Comment: How can i use it now?
@var $block \Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View\GalleryXY in phtml?

Comment: After override Block class, `$block->getGalleryImages()` this function first call from override `Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View\GalleryXY` class, if method is not in this class then method call from magento core class.